# Restriction and extension of scalars between flat algebras and their completion over a DVR and ideals.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So, in a proof I am currently reading I have stumbled upon the following.

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring, $\hat{R}$ its completion and $t$ a uniformizing parameter for $R.$ Let $A$ be a flat $R$-algebra and $\hat{A} = A \otimes \hat{R}.$ Let $I$ be an ideal such that $t \hat{A} \subset I$. Let us set $I_0 = I \cap A$ (this makes sense since $A \rightarrow \hat{A}$ is injective). Consider then $I_0\hat{A}$. The proof I am reading claims that $I_0\hat{A} = I$, but I don't see it. Can anyone give me a hint or a proof of why this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $t \hat{A} \cap A = t A$, and so $tA \subset I_0$.  Now use the fact that $\hat{A}/t\hat{A} = A/tA.$

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Comment: @user26857: Because $\hat{R}/t\hat{R} = R/tR = k$ (the residue field).

Comment: Where does the flatness of $A$ over $R$ come into play?

Comment: @user26857 This is to ensure the injectivity of $A \rightarrow \hat{A}$.

Comment: And why need $A\to\hat A$ to be injective? (The contraction and extension of ideals work for ring homomorphisms as well.)